# List of Map entries from map

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to get a (sorted by value) list of map entries from a Map. I tried this:

```
List<Pair<String, AtomicInteger>> expectedList = expectedMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> -e.getValue().get()))
            .map(e -> new Pair<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but if I try to substitute Pair with Map.Entry, it tells me that Map.Entry is abstract and cannot be instantiated. Is there a way to adapt this construct to get a list of entries instead of a list of pairs?

Comment: How about using [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html), which implements `Map.Entry` ?

Comment: `List<Entry<String, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> -e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());` ?

Comment: @Turing85 +1. The solution is more general as it lets the specific type instantation to java.

Comment: Wait, if you're already starting with entries, and you want to end up with entries, why are you trying to map it to something else?

Comment: @khelwood `int five = new Integer(5)`. Why do it easy when you can complicate it.

Comment: Why do you actually want to create a new `Map.Entry`?

Comment: See answer below, I just edited.

Comment: @khelwood to check for equality of two Maps in a JUnit test

Answer (score 4):

See the [Javadoc for Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html):

> Interface Map.Entry
>
> All Known Implementing Classes:
>   [AbstractMap.SimpleEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html), [AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html)

Pick one implementing class that suits your needs, for example

```
List<Entry<String, AtomicInteger>> expectedList = expectedMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> -e.getValue().get()))
            .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But you could also just remove the `map` and use the entries that `entrySet()` returns:

```
List<Entry<String, AtomicInteger>> expectedList = expectedMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> -e.getValue().get()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

PS.: If you are comparing primitive data types, you should use the right method like `comparingInt`. This avoids unnecessary boxing.

Comment: I am comparing it with another List of Entries in the context of a JUnit test. What I get implementing this solution is `java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <[]>
     but: was <[this=2, file=1, for=1, project=1, is=1, an=1, just=1, example=1]>
Expected :is <[]>`

Comment: Obviously expected is the result of the code in question, and the bit after "was" would be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need to map `Map.Entry` to something else if you need `Map.Entry`.

Here's my take. I've opted to first create a list of entries and then sort it. Also used mor of the built-in API to construct the comparator.

```
List<Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger>> expectedList = 
    new ArrayList<>(expectedMap.entrySet());

Collections.sort(expectedList,
    Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
        Comparator.comparingInt(AtomicInteger::get).reversed());
```